# i try to show images from online directory but images not shown properly or break down

Tags: php

```
<?php

$path = "/home/qeplaho/public_html/image/";
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
echo "<table>";
echo"<tr>";
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file){
//echo "<td><input type=CHECKBOX name=$file></td>";
echo "<td><img width='200' height='200' src='/home/qeplaho/public_html/image/'  ><br>
      $file
  </td>";
  //$file
  //alt='$file'
}
}
echo"<tr/>";
echo"</table>";
closedir($dir_handle);

?>
```

here is my code i want to show the all images in this directory 'image' but images not shown properly and break down what i can do?pplz help me as i m new in php and provide me an easy solution related to this

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to replace this

```
echo "<td><img width='200' height='200' src='/home/qeplaho/public_html/image/'  ><br>
      $file
</td>";
```

with this

```
echo "<td><img width='200' height='200' src='/image/$file'/></td>";
```